# Creating a filter with tags from an array of profiles

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of profiles.

Each item in the array has an array of tags.

eg. `devs = [ { name: "John", skills: ["react", "javascript"]}, { name: "Jane", skills: ["HTML", "javascript"]} ]`

I first want to create an array of all unique skills.

Then I want to filter the devs array according to the skills I select. I want to map that array of unique skills as buttons, and when a button is clicked, filter the mapped devs array.

```
const devs = [ 
{ name: "John", skills: ["react", "javascript"]}, 
{ name: "Jane", skills: ["HTML", "javascript"]} ];

const allSkills = //Need all unique values from devs.skills
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);

return (
<> 
Filter:
{allSkills.map((skill) => <button onClick=() => setFilters(??)>{skill}</button>)}

{devs.map((dev) => <p>{dev.name} Skills:
    {dev.skills.map((skill) => <span>{skill}</span>)} 
                </p>))} //need to filter this based on filters


</>
)
```

It's in a React component, I took it as far as I could.

Comment: You can use the array `reduce` method and `Set` data structure instead of `map`

Answer (score 2):

So to get an array of unique skills you can use spread operator with `concat` and `Set` and then you can use `filter` method to get developers based on the selected skill.

```js
const devs = [{
    name: "John",
    skills: ["react", "javascript"]
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    skills: ["HTML", "javascript"]
  }
];

const skills = Array.from(new Set([].concat(...devs.map(({ skills }) => skills))))

const  filterBySkill = (skill) => {
  return devs
    .filter(({ skills }) => skills.includes(skill))
    .map(({ name }) => name)
}

console.log(filterBySkill('javascript'))
console.log(filterBySkill('react'))
console.log(skills)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get list of unique skills you could use `Set` in combination with `map` e.g.

```
let uniqueSkills = new Set(devs.map(x=> x.skills).flat());
```

Then if you want to filter your inital array, you could use something like this:

```
let filteredList = devs.filter(x=> x.skills.includes(word));
```

where `word` is a string or a variable that containts string with concrete skill to find.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the other answer if you don't want to create a `Set` and convert it back to array, using `flat` and `reduce`:

```js
const devs = [ 
{ name: "John", skills: ["react", "javascript"]}, 
{ name: "Jane", skills: ["HTML", "javascript"]} ];

const allSkills = devs.map(dev => dev.skills).flat().reduce(
    (arr, val) => {
        if (!arr.includes(val)) arr.push(val); 
        return arr
    },
    []
)

console.log(allSkills)
```